# How to activate the Virtual Desktop feature on Fortigate 100A?

Tags: firewall, desktop, virtualization

We did recently update the firmware on our Fortigate 100A box and after the upgrade we tried to use the "Virtual Desktop" feature. (This isn't a new firmware feature) We can't find a way to activate or use it. We read the manuals and set everything according to the book. The only thing that we couldn't work out was the new version of the offline virtual desktop tool (which wasn't necessary for this feature because normally it works in the browser). Does anyone have any experience on "Virtual Desktop" of Fortigate devices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after some online chat with Fortigate support we learned that this feature is only supported on Win XP and Vista OS'es. We were trying to use it on Win 7. It really worked on XP.